# How to optimize this query? I am making a request to Dynamics CRM. Console: System.TimeoutException: The request channel timed out while waiting

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm

```
public List<T> GetMarketActivities(win_market market)
{
    var team = (EntityReference)((AliasedValue)market["bu.win_defaultteam"]).Value;

    var query = new QueryExpression(_activity.LogicalName);
    query.TopCount = 1000;//I tried reducing this to 100 but still the same
    query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(ActivityPointer.Fields.ActivityId, ActivityPointer.Fields.OwnerId);
    query.Criteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression(ActivityPointer.Fields.OwnerId, ConditionOperator.NotEqual, team.Id));

    LinkEntity caseLink = new LinkEntity(_activity.LogicalName, Incident.EntityLogicalName,             ActivityPointer.Fields.RegardingObjectId, Incident.Fields.IncidentId, JoinOperator.Inner);
    query.LinkEntities.Add(caseLink);

    LinkEntity contactLink = new LinkEntity(Incident.EntityLogicalName, Contact.EntityLogicalName, Incident.Fields.CustomerId, Contact.Fields.ContactId, JoinOperator.Inner);
    contactLink.LinkCriteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression(Contact.Fields.win_Country, ConditionOperator.Equal, market.win_marketcountry.Id));
    contactLink.LinkCriteria.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression(Contact.Fields.win_Brand, ConditionOperator.Equal, market.win_marketbrand.Id));
    caseLink.LinkEntities.Add(contactLink);

    var activities = _organizationService.RetrieveMultiple(query);//issue here

    if (activities.Entities?.Count > 0)
    {
        return activities.Entities.Select(e => e.ToEntity<T>()).ToList();
    }

    return new List<T>();
}
```

I tried reducing the TopCount to 100 but it is still giving an issue,

I suspect that linking all the entities then making the query to dynamics CRM is the issue, however I am not sure how to optimize this query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the question in my opinion should not have been closed, I voted to reopen it and I upvoted to remove that -1. The code is quite normal, consider that the max results will be always 5000, so also if you have a million of activities at least you should get the first 5000. best guess is that you are onpremise, but my suggestion will be to run these query separately and see if the problem happens because you are linking a specific entity. hope it helps

Comment: I tried a similar query on a Dynamics 365 CE online system and had no issues. Are you working on a on premises system, which version? Does your system have particularly massive tables? Did you try the `QueryExpression.NoLock` switch?

Comment: Hi @Henk van Boeijen, Yes I did try with the QueryExpression.NoLock =  true but it did not help, I think I have to break this query into a smaller one which I am struggling with

Comment: @jbm_force_tranquille: when you are working with a on premises system, recomputing table statistics can help, as well as adding indexes.

Comment: Hi @Henk van Boeijen, Yes true I am currently trying to add indexes on the country. And no I am not working with a on premises system.

Comment: @jbm_force_tranquille, the queried activities are related to cases. Perhaps you only need active cases and/or cases that are related to a specific team. If so, you could consider querying cases as the primary table and left join the activities that are related to those cases. Sometimes this can help the query optimizer finding a more efficient execution plan.